# DRF - data property typing [mypy]

Tags: django-rest-framework, mypy, typing

I want to annotate serializer data property `Myserializer(instance).data` with structure that know key-values (something like typedDict). I have installed django-stubs and drf-stubs.

Mypy gives me an error (and does it correctly):

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type
"ReturnDict[Any, Any]", variable has type "myType")  [assignment]
```

How should I annotate my case correctly? Is there a better way to do this than using `cast` or ignore overriding like:

```
@property
def data(self) -> myType:
    return super().data  # type: ignore[return-value]
```

django 5.0
drf: 3.14
drf-stubs: 3.14.4
django-stubs: 4.2.6

Comment: Cast or type-ignore, there's no way around this. You know the type better, but it's not expressible in general - you just tell to the typechecker that you know better. `mypy` is your helpe tool, not smth that should influence your code significantly. If you find yourself writing a lot of boilerplate to please `mypy` where a symple dynamic solution would work, go ahead and use a dynamic solution - a couple of ignore comments is better that terrible code without them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cash or Type-ignore, or try to override it.